# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type - React

Tags: reactjs, web3js

Hello I am doing blockchain with React but when I import Web 3 using

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
```

it give me this error:

```
./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (225:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }
|         return signed({
|             ...tx,
|             chainId: args[0],
```

I am using node 14.17.1 and I created this using

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version 1.1.5
```

and I installed web3 using

```
npm install web3
```

This is the tsconfig.json file and this file showing errors as well

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./lib",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
      "./src"
    ]
   }
```

and index.js code where the error is referring

```
return signed({
            ...tx,
            chainId: args[0],
            nonce: args[1],
            networkId: args[2],
            ...args[3] // Will either be gasPrice or maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas
        });
```

Comment: Which version of Node are you using? And what builder(s) are you using? [And remember to put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 14.17.1 @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: i installed web 3 using npm install --save web3

Comment: No, really, put those details in your post [as per the posting guidelines](/help/how- to-ask). If you're using typescript, Node can't natively run that. So what else are you using to make Node run your code? And remember, again, don't tell me, tell _everyone_ by putting that information in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project's created with `--scripts-version 1.1.5` which mean its babel  can not parse `...`, consider to use higher `scripts-version`. For me, I upgraded from `1.1.4` to `3.2.0`