# Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: webpack, web3js, babel-loader

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (225:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }
|         return signed({
|             ...tx,
|             chainId: args[0],
|             nonce: args[1],
```

Got this error when I started an open source app named [multisende](https://github.com/rstormsf/multisender#how-to-setup-dev-environment)r. I actually didn't know much about webpack or babel configuration.

Extra files:

```
// tsconfig.js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}


// package.json
{
  "name": "multi-sender-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "GPL3",
  "homepage": "https://rstormsf.github.io/multisender",
  "dependencies": {
    "bignumber.js": "^6.0.0",
    "csvtojson": "^1.1.9",
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "json-validator": "0.0.34",
    "mobx": "^3.5.1",
    "mobx-react": "^4.4.2",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.15.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-app-rewire-mobx": "^1.0.7",
    "react-app-rewire-preact": "^1.0.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-json-view": "^1.16.1",
    "react-radio-group": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.2.6",
    "react-validation": "^3.0.7",
    "splash-screen": "^4.0.1",
    "store2": "^2.7.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.30"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/assets/stylesheets/application.scss -o src/assets/stylesheets --output-style=compressed",
    "watch-css": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build-css\"",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build -o rstorm"
  }
}
```

I tried to solve this by upgrading all the packages to latest version, but it created another error: The "injectBabelPlugin" helper has been deprecated as of v2.0. You can use customize-cra plugins in replacement

I read documentation for using customize-cra but I couldn't understand it. So I want to know if can solve this issue without updating packages?

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69279705/5732802

Answer (score 0):

Check your `node` version, perhaps the `spread` operator is not supported. You must replace "...tx".

Versions until `8.6` don't support the spread operator.

See [spread operator compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#browser_compatibility)

Spread in array literals: > v5.0.0

Spread in function calls: > v5.0.0

Spread in object literals: > v8.3.0